# JavaFX Blurry HBOX with CSS

Tags: css, javafx

[image]

css

```
   HBox:hover{
    -fx-background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .25);
    -fx-scale-x: 1.10px;
    -fx-scale-y: 1.10px;
    -fx-scale-z: 1.10px;
}
```

A little difficult to tell on the picture, but its pretty blurry to me when I scale it. How can I fix this? Applies to buttons as well, which I'm also trying to do it on.

Answer (score -1):

I'm gonna go out on a limb and assume that the content is blurry and not the HBox itself since I can clearly see the crisp margin.

If you're scaling up any png, there will be a loss of detail based on how small the bitmap is.

It is a good idea to either have high res copies for small, medium and large icons and whatnot, or use a large image source which you scale down.

Also, useless scale increments such as 1.1px ... i mean... you want it to scale 1 pixel into 1.1 pixels? ... how would the monitor go about plotting that stuff? Pretty sure "px" shouldn't even be there since it's a discrete value, not a pixel reference.

Scaling stuff essentially multiplies it's dimension by a number... say you want to scale a 100x100 px box to 1.5 times it's size, it's scale would be 1.5 =----> 150x150px

Moreover, you should make sure that whatever you scale, the resulting dimensions should always be even, and failing that, never be anything else than an integer.

Say you want to plot 5.23556 pixels... the software will tell your monitor driver what the expected size shoul nd be............i.e............. ^--- that one ........ and the driver will do it's best to approximate that value somehow. It usually does this by combining colors and alpha values together in order to give off the illusion of antialising.

So to recap....

1. scale LARGE bitmap images DOWN, not SMALL IMAGES UP. ... or use SVG.
2. 1.1px ??? look into that..
3. 1.1 scale is kind of wierd ... use 2.0, 3.0, 100.0 etc.

Comment: Not really sure how you think 1.1 is a useless scale, makes a very clear and obvious effect of slightly enlarging it on mouse hover. I can't do 2, as that's way to large. Didn't really answer my question either, but I suppose I could just enlarge the image and by default scale it down, essentially doing the opposite of what I am now

Comment: 1.1 is a bad idea because you're essentially dealing with pixel matrices. basically whenever you scale something you tell the rendering engine to transform that pixel matrix somehow. This needs some forethought as things can get complicated fast if you're dealing with odd scaling (3x, 7x etc), or non-integer (7.3x). This is because the rendering engine will start aggregating pixel values... so say you have 1px 255 0 0 (pure blue), next to another one which is 255 255 255(pure white), if you scale that down to half, the engine will generate a weird pale blue pixel

Comment: And this can become unpredictable fast. Add transparency into the equation, and the resulting pixel map ... basically looks bad. There's detail loss, color consistency loss, compression artefacts that show up out of nowhere, contrast loss, etc. Rule of thumb is to essentially use even scale (2x, 4x, 6x, 100x), and basically make sure that the resulting scale is divisible by the original size. or if you want to scale it down, multiples of 25% ... or 12.5%. ... assuming your images are not something like 101px x203px.

Comment: It works both ways... upscaling small stuff can yield large images with low detail levels because of pretty much the same reasons... the render engine turns 1px into 1px*scale. ... so 1px multiplied by 1.1 yields some data that gets merged into the adjacent pixel(s)... so yeah... detail loss here as well.